# Why are these application.properties not working?

Tags: java, properties, config, javabeans, quarkus

I've been implementing a simple quarkus application for creating a CMIS API to work with Alfresco. Followed [this tutorial](https://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/concepts/opencmis-ext-intro.html) (just to give a little insight)

Everything went well until I decided to use properties to pass the session parameters. I've added those to application.properties in main/resources/application.properties like this:

```
# Session properties
session.host=localhost
session.port=80
session.url=http://localhost:80/alfresco/api/-default-/cmis/versions/1.1/atom
session.compression=true
session.cache_ttl_objects=0
```

Then I tried defining them directly in the class I was using them, but since was getting null values I looked around for why was that happening and found [this](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/1632). That being said, I followed [this](https://github.com/ElinaValieva/quarkus-quickstarts/commit/c2025524b7f28146f92394ebce80ae92ad51fc89#diff-c25ddd1a9d5a96e3e384971a697248b7c17173a41e5cf8538020a4d17f775b93) structure which is supposed to fix that.

I created the class SessionConfig.java:

```
package com.c4pa.cmisservice;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.eclipse.microprofile.config.inject.ConfigProperty;

import io.quarkus.arc.config.ConfigProperties;

@ConfigProperties(prefix = "session") // Already tried without this, using session.url, etc on each Property
public class SessionConfig {

    @Inject // Already tried without this
    @ConfigProperty(name = "url")
    private String url;

    @Inject // Already tried without this
    @ConfigProperty(name = "compression", defaultValue = "true")
    private String compression;

    @Inject // Already tried without this
    @ConfigProperty(name = "cache_ttl_objects", defaultValue = "0")
    private String cacheTTLObjects;

    public String getUrl(){
        return this.url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url){
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getCompression(){
        return this.compression;
    }

    public void setCompression(String compression){
        this.compression = compression;
    }

    public String getCacheTTLObjects(){
        return this.cacheTTLObjects;
    }

    public void setCacheTTLObjects(String cacheTTLObjects){
        this.cacheTTLObjects = cacheTTLObjects;
    }

}
```

And I'm trying to use the properties on this class CMISClient.java:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class CMISClient {

    private static Map<String, Session> connections = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Session>();

    public CMISClient() { }

    @Inject
    SessionConfig sessionConfig;

    public Session getSession(String connectionName, String username, String pwd) {
        Session session = connections.get(connectionName);
        System.out.println(sessionConfig.getUrl() + "|" + sessionConfig.getCompression() + "|" + sessionConfig.getCacheTTLObjects());
        if (session == null) {
            // No connection to Alfresco available, creating a new one
            SessionFactory sessionFactory = SessionFactoryImpl.newInstance();
            Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
            parameters.put(SessionParameter.USER, username);
            parameters.put(SessionParameter.PASSWORD, pwd);
            parameters.put(SessionParameter.ATOMPUB_URL, sessionConfig.getUrl());
            parameters.put(SessionParameter.BINDING_TYPE, BindingType.ATOMPUB.value());
            parameters.put(SessionParameter.COMPRESSION, sessionConfig.getCompression());
            parameters.put(SessionParameter.CACHE_TTL_OBJECTS, sessionConfig.getCacheTTLObjects());
            ...
        }
        return session;
    }
...
}
```

But when I call the endpoint which calls the getSession method it results in **org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.NullPointerException** on the println of the getSession method. Of course, if I comment that, I'll get the same exception on the parameters.put lines instead.

Reversed stacktrace if it is useful:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.c4pa.cmisservice.CMISClient.getSession(CMISClient.java:46)
    at com.c4pa.cmisservice.CMISResource.createConnection(CMISResource.java:42)
    at com.c4pa.cmisservice.CMISResource.send(CMISResource.java:25)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:170)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:130)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:643)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:507)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$2(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:457)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:459)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:419)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:393)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:68)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:492)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:261)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:164)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:247)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.RequestDispatcher.service(RequestDispatcher.java:73)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.dispatch(VertxRequestHandler.java:136)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.access$000(VertxRequestHandler.java:40)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler$1.run(VertxRequestHandler.java:97)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.CleanableExecutor$CleaningRunnable.run(CleanableExecutor.java:231)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2046)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1578)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1452)
    at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
    at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:479)
Resulted in: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:106)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:372)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:218)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:519)
    ... 20 more
```

Any ideas on why is this happening? Thanks a lot in advance.

EDIT:

```
@Path("/file")
public class CMISResource {

    private CMISClient cmisClient;
    private String connectionName;
    private Session session;

    @GET
    @Path("/send")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String send() throws IOException {
        this.createConnection();
        Folder folder = this.cmisClient.createFolder(session);
        Document document = cmisClient.createDocument(session, folder);
        return document.getName() + " was succesfully created (at least I hope so)";
    }

    private void createConnection() {
        this.cmisClient = new CMISClient();
        this.connectionName = "c4paAlf01";
        this.session = cmisClient.getSession(connectionName, "username", "password");
    }
```

Comment: How is `CMISClient` being used?

Comment: @geoand I've just edited the question with the code of the class using CMISClient

Comment: Are you sure he NPE doesn't happen because `sessionConfig` is null rather than a call to `sessionConfig` method?

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci sessionConfig is null. That's the problem (at least for now). I'm injecting it from the class which has the ConfigProperty's so I don't understand why is it null

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
@ConfigProperties(prefix = "session")
public class SessionConfig {

  public String url;
  public String compression;
  public String cacheTTLObjects;
}
```